# Proof of the Isoperimetric Theorem in Higher Dimensions

Tags: calculus, geometry

I have read a couple of nice proofs for the isoperimetric theorem in 2 dimensions. Is there a simple proof for the isoperimetric theorem in $n$ dimensions? In other words, how do you prove that the $n$-dimensional "sphere" is the geometric figure with the largest "volume" with a given "area"?

Comment: www.math.utah.edu/~treiberg/Steiner/SteinerSlides.pdf

Comment: that $dS$ an infinitesimal piece of sphere is the minimizer of $\min_S\frac{area(S)}{volume(convexHull(S,c))}$ (where $c$ is the center of the sphere) ?

Answer (score 3):

The proof of the isoperimetric inequality in higher dimensions follows easily from the [Brunn-Minkowski inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality#Isoperimetric_inequality_in_.7F.27.22.60UNIQ--postMath-00000019-QINU.60.22.27.7F). This approach is particularly well suited to bodies with non-smooth boundaries and also works for [non-Euclidean geometries](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/wol1/doi/10.1002/mana.19480010202/abstract).

Self-contained proofs that do not rely on Brunn-Minkowski were given for bodies with smooth boundaries by [Schmidt](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Other/hopf-samelson.pdf) and [Dilts](https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/rhumj/vol11/iss2/2/), for compact Lebesgue measurable sets by
[Hadwiger](https://eudml.org/doc/160266) and for sets of finite perimeter by [de Giorgi](https://books.google.de/books?id=M2viBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA86&lpg=PA86&dq=de+giorgi+proof+isoperimetric&source=bl&ots=azuenq5B0O&sig=FPOAatPdfeg7jnAbTwyiOkQg1bQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR9qqb0IXSAhUBPxQKHRYqA04Q6AEIZDAH#v=onepage&q&f=false).